# Find an orthonormal basis in which $E$ is represented by matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $W$ be the subspace of $R^2$ spanned by the vector $(3, 4)$. Using the standard inner product, let $E$ be the orthogonal projection of $R^2$ onto $W$. 
Find

(a) a formula for $E(x_1, x_2)$ ;

(b) the matrix of $E$ in the standard ordered basis;

(c) $W^\bot$;

(d) an orthonormal basis in which $E$ is represented by matrix

\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}

**Attempt:**
$$E(x_1,x_2)=\frac{((x_1,x_2)|(3,4))}{25}(3,4)= \left( \frac{9x_1+12x_2}{25},\frac{ 12x_1+16x_2}{25} \right) $$

So in the standard basis the matrix is $$\frac{1}{25}\begin{bmatrix}9 & 12 \\ 12 & 16\end{bmatrix}.$$

The set $W^\bot$ is $\{ (x,y) \in R^2 ; ((x,y)|(x',y'))=0 \;\; \forall (x',y') \in W \} =$ $\{ (x,y) \in R^2 ; x = - \frac{4}{3} y \} $.

now I can not find a basis such that the matrix of E in this is \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
Apparently the system 
$E(a,b)=(1,0);E(c,d)=(0,0)
$

has no solution, if I'm doing it right. Any suggestion?

Comment: Hint: The columns of the matrix are the images of the basis vectors. What vectors are mapped to themselves by $E$?

Comment: I was trying to do this, but the system seems to have no solution $E(a,b)=(1,0)$.

Comment: The system you should be trying to solve is $E(a,b)=(a,b)$. However, forget the algebra for a moment. Think about this geometrically. Draw a picture, even!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an orthonormal basis $u,v$ such that $E(v)=0$ and $E(u)=\pmatrix{1\\0} $ *coordinated in the new basis*, i.e. $E(u) =1\cdot u+0\cdot v=u$.

But such $u, v$ vectors you already know.

Comment: It worked! I got the base $ (\dfrac{3}{4},1); \,\, (\dfrac{-1}{3},\dfrac{1}{4}) $

Comment: Well, it's rather $u=\pmatrix{3/5\\4/5}$ and $v=\pm\pmatrix{-4/5\\3/5}$.